# My xcode4 is missing some iPhone templates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I am new to iPhone development.

I have installed xcode4 in my Mac and started to read some online tutorials. I found that the xcode in my Mac is missing some iPhone templates. Such as 'View-based application' template.

Here is a screen capture from my Mac:

[image: Screenshot of new project screen]

Most hello world tutorials are using 'View-based application'. I cannot start to learn iPhone programming unless I find 'View-based application' in my xcode. I hope someone can help, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View-based application is "Single View Application" in XCode 4

Navigation-based application is "Master-Detail Application"